# Push variable value into new notepad window (without saving a file)

Tags: powershell

Lets say I have a variable with a value assigned.

I'd like to direct an output of this variable to a new notepad window, but without saving a file.

I thought it can be done simply by ">" but it's redirecting value to a newly created file (C:\Windows\system32\notepad).

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this: https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/send-text-to-notepad

Comment: Notepad doesn't support that. The solution linked by Paxz uses non-managed Windows API code to achieve that, which is pretty heavy-handed for that, but that's about all you'll be able to do. I would recommend looking at changing your requirements.

Comment: If you like do these kind of things, I would look into an RPA (Robotic Process Automation) application, such as [UIPath](https://www.uipath.com/?gclid=CjwKCAiA0uLgBRABEiwAecFnkyXEItkzhcSHM0IjxuFuPdxWdGK2HtvCQaiwCzTzxKmceg876OzDZxoCAZoQAvD_BwE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use the function suggested by @Paxz

```
function Out-Notepad {
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [String]
    [AllowEmptyString()] 
    $Text
  )
  begin {
    $sb = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
  }
  process {
    $null = $sb.AppendLine($Text)
  }
  end {
    $text = $sb.ToString()
    $process = Start-Process notepad -PassThru
    $null = $process.WaitForInputIdle()
    $sig = '
      [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
      [DllImport("User32.dll")]public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
    '
    $type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -Name APISendMessage -PassThru
    $hwnd = $process.MainWindowHandle
    [IntPtr]$child = $type::FindWindowEx($hwnd, [IntPtr]::Zero, "Edit", $null)
    $null = $type::SendMessage($child, 0x000C, 0, $text)
  }
}
```

([Source](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/send-text-to-notepad))

Put it into your `$profile`. Restart PowerShell.

Then you can do:

```
"Hello World" | Out-Notepad
```

As @briantist pointed out, this is kinda overkill though.

**Option 2**

Use the clipboard:

```
"Hello World" | Set-Clipboard; Start-Process notepad
```

Then simply paste the text inside the open window.

Comment: This is not working anymore on Windows 11.